# Is There A Consistent Method That's Not Fixed/Update() or OnGUI() in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

So, I'm working on a unity project and I find myself with functions that don't need to be called 33 times per second or every 0.02 seconds. I'm not sure how often then GUI renders. Is there a method like the aforementioned that takes place maybe.. four times per second?

Because if not, I'd have to make one and that seems like it in itself will cost resources.

Comment: On a sidenote: OnGui shouldn't really be used with the newer versions of unity since there is the new UI for ingame menus etc. OnGui is mostly meant for custom editors.

Comment: @GunnarB. Good to know, thank you sire.

Comment: @GunnarB. What should I be using? I'm a little late to the party on five.

Comment: The UI objects you can create in the scene. Here is a manual about this: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UISystem.html

Comment: @GunnarB. Much thanks, brother.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the method that has to be executed X times per second, and call it using `InvokeRepeating`. 
Something like this:

```
InvokeRepeating("methodName", 0.0, 1.0/X);
```

You could call this one in the `Start()` function.

```
//Example (executing "methodName" 4 times per second).
void Start(){
   InvokeRepeating("methodName", 0.0, 0.25f);
}
```

Comment: Could you put it in C# for me I'm JS illiterate atm.

Comment: Hi Thomas, it is in C# already. just enclose it in the Start and change the parameter as required. I update the answer, though.

Comment: Sorry I guess I'm just missing the hypotheticals. Are you basing this off delta time?

Comment: Yes, it's called every 0.25 seconds, in an absolute way (it starts after 0.0 secs - second parameter - and it's called every 0.25 secs - third one -).

Comment: Alright. Thank you sir. I feel like this is something unity should have.

Comment: @ThomasCaplan `InvokeRepeating` is a thing that actually comes along with unity (or more precisely with MonoBehaviour).

Comment: Oh wow! That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you sir. I'm sorry it's so hard to get information into my skull.

Answer (score 1):

for this cases you can use a [corrutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html)

---

this method can help you

```
void Start(){

    StartCoroutine(yourMethod());
}

IEnumerator yourMethod()
{
   while(true){
    // do something every 4 seconds
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(4);
   }
}
```

**important**

- every method that you create with IEnumerator must to be called inside the Coroutine();
- yield return new WaitForSeconds(4) put this method to wait for 4 seconds.